Retrieve images from mysql database in django
I'm new to django and creating a listing site.  I want to retrieve the users' image number 1 of 2 to display as thumbnails for a category page.  I have since been able to retrieve the images for user's 'view listing' page, but not for my category page.
I tried applying the url tags in the same way I did for the 'view listings' page, as below:
<div class="flex-container">
            {% if listing.image1 %}
              <img src="{{ listing.image1.url }}?" class="small-image" alt="Small image 1">
            {% endif %}
            {% if listing.image2 %}
              <img src="{{ listing.image2.url }}?" class="small-image" alt="Small image 2">
            {% endif %}
          </div>

But this approach didn't work.  So after some research, I used this  in the 'category page'
<h1>{{ category.title }}</h1>
    <p></p>
    <ul>
        {% for pedal in pedals %}
            <li>
                <h3>{{ pedal.pedal_name }}</h3>
                <a href="{% url 'pedal_detail' pedal_id=pedal.id %}">
                    <img src="{% if pedal.images.all|length > 0 %}{{ pedal.images.first.image.url }}{% else %}{% static 'path/to/default/image.jpg' %}{% endif %}" alt="Pedal Thumbnail" class="pedal-thumbnail">
                </a>
            </li>
            <p></p>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

But again, this hasn't worked.  I'm unsure of the best way to do this.  I've included other relevant code below to help advise.
settings.py
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "cloudinary_storage.storage.StaticHashedCloudinaryStorage"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")] # development
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles") # production
CLOUDINARY_URL = os.environ.get("CLOUDINARY_URL")   
MEDIA_URL = "/images/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/images/')
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "cloudinary_storage.storage.MediaCloudinaryStorage"

# Cloudinary Storage Configuration
CLOUDINARY_STORAGE = {
    'CLOUD_NAME': os.environ.get('CLOUD_NAME'),
    'API_KEY': os.environ.get('API_KEY'),
    'API_SECRET': os.environ.get('API_SECRET'),
    
}

views.py
def category_page(request, category_id):
    # Retrieve the category based on ID
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, id=category_id)
    # Retrieve all pedals belonging to selected category
    pedals = Pedal.objects.filter(category_name=category)
    return render(request, 'category_page.html', {'category': category, 'pedals': pedals})

def pedal_detail(request, pedal_id):
    pedal = get_object_or_404(Pedal, id=pedal_id)
    return render(request, 'pedal_detail.html', {'pedal': pedal})

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('my_listings/', views.my_listings, name='my_listings'),
    path('create/', views.create_listing, name='create_listing'),
    path('listings/<int:pk>/', views.listing_detail, name='listing_detail'),
    path('listings/<int:pk>/update/', views.update_listing, name='update_listing'),
    path('listings/<int:pk>/delete/', views.delete_listing, name='delete_listing'),
    path('listings/category/<int:category_id>/', views.category_page, name='category_page'),
    path('listings/pedal/<int:pedal_id>/', views.pedal_detail, name='pedal_detail'),

]

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Have you added the static file handled in your urls.py code
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatters = [
    #url
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


Hi Aditya, I've added that to my project urls.py and I now get the following django debug error:
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://8000-shieldsjohn-stompbox-hc42ee3uqm8.ws-eu114.gitpod.io/listings/listings/category/1/
Using the URLconf defined in stompbox.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^images/(?P.*)$
The current path, listings/listings/category/1/, didn’t match any of these.

Probably, i am not understand the whole problem, but i dont see any static url handler.
Are you have in urls.py static files handler? If not, try add folloving:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


Thanks Maxim.  No I don't have that in my urls.py but haven't needed to in the image retrieval for another page.  What does this do, I've not used it before.  It hasn't worked in my urls.py, I get a 'urlpatterns is not defined' error.

if image lays on another server - you dont need it. If your images lays on your server - you need to do something with static. on django level or on web-server layer.
